# Get Id from url() in angular

Tags: angularjs

How to get `id` from url()
This is my `url`

```
http://localhost:59113/Project/EditProject?id=2
```

I did it using jquery..

```
var url = document.URL;
        var id = /id=([^&]+)/.exec(url)[1];
        var result = id ? id : ' ';
```

But I need to do it using angular.Can anyone help me?
I tried this too(updated part)

```
 var app = angular
                .module("intranet_App", [])
                    app.config("$routeProvider", function ($routeProvider) {
                        $routeProvider.when('/view1/:param1/:param2', {
                            templateUrl: 'Project/EditProject.html',
                            controller: 'myCtrl'
                        })
                    })
                    .controller("myCtrl", ["$scope", "$http", "$location", "$route",  function ($scope, $http, $location, $route) {
                    // alert($location.id)
                    var a = $route.current.params;
                    alert(a.id)
                }])
```

Comment: I tried this `console.log($location.search().id)` its showing undefined.

Comment: Try `console.log($location.id)`

Comment: @Hadi yes tried..nothing is coming

Comment: Did you saw my sample? and how tried that?
 please display it.http://plnkr.co/edit/PRM2vbopgettn6Ci9T7j?p=preview

Comment: The first `url` that you displayed is different with second `url`. first `url` have query param but second not have.

Answer (score 3):

Using [`$routeParams`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams) you can get id,

**Updated answer**

Use `$route` instead of `$routeParams`. Note that the $routeParams are only updated after a route change completes successfully. This means that you cannot rely on $routeParams being correct in route resolve functions. Instead you can use $route.current.params to access the new route's parameters.

```
$route.current.params
```

**EDIT**

You must do this in `.config()` method

```
app.config(function($routeProvider){
      $routeProvider.when('/view1/:param1/:param2', {
            templateUrl: 'Project/EditProject.html',
            controller: 'myCtrl'
      })
})
```

Comment: Check now and let me know

Comment: You forgot to include `$routeProvider` in dependency injection

Comment: no, please check my answer once more. `app.config(function($routeProvider){` an then u get id using `a.id`

Comment: yes i have added as you said but this error is coming `Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]` I have injected all params.

Comment: `app.config("$routeProvider", function ($routeProvider) {` change this to `app.config(function ($routeProvider) {`

Answer (score 0):

$location.search() returns an object, so as per above url

```
http://localhost:59113/Project/EditProject?id=2
```

$location.search().id will fetch you an answer.

More Info:

If you are getting an empty object with $location.search(), it is probably because Angular is using the hashbang strategy, To fix this you need to change the following in config file

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

`$location.search()` will return an object of key-value pairs.
in your case:You could access this value directly with `$location.search().id`